# Map JUL levels to AppEngine web console levels

Tags: java, google-app-engine, java.util.logging

The AppEngine web console allows filtering of different log levels:

- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- CRITICAL

AppEngine uses java.utils.logging (JUL) but JUL defines different log-levels to those used in the web console, namely:

- FINEST (lowest value)
- FINER
- FINE
- CONFIG
- INFO
- WARNING
- SEVERE (highest value)

In code this means that logging at INFO or WARING works well.
 LOG.info("some info message);
 LOG.warning("some warn message");

NB I have /logging.properties with

```
# Set the default logging level for all loggers
.level = ALL
```

But no log shows: from

```
 LOG.fine("some fine message);
 LOG.finer("some finer message);
 LOG.finest("some finest message);
```

What code do I write to get logs to appear at DEBUG in the web console?

Comment: Why the mark down on the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

1. To add the following to your code:

   ```
       import java.util.logging.Level;

       .
       .
       .
       LOG.setLevel(Level.ALL);

       LOG.warning("Warning message logged");
       LOG.severe("severe debug message logged");
       LOG.info("info message logged");
       LOG.config("config message logged");
       LOG.fine("some fine message");
       LOG.finer("some finer message");
       LOG.finest("some finest message");
   ```
2. The second option is to add your logging.properties file to appengine-web.xml as suggested [here](http://www.mkyong.com/google-app-engine/configure-logging-in-google-app-engine/):

> ```
>   <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
>   <system-properties>
>     <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
>   </system-properties>
> ```

Note it should be located under WEB-INF or change that location in the previous file.

Comment: I don't know who marked you down. But this was great thanks. It looks like config, fine, finer, finest all map to DEBUG.

Comment: Yes, the 7 standard Java levels are comprised into only 5 in GAE. But by configuring .level you could de-activate them programatically.

Answer (score 1):

### Just for reference:

- [image] **DEBUG**: FINEST, FINER, FINE, CONFIG.
- [image] **INFO**: INFO.
- [image] **WARN**: WARNING.
- [image] **ERROR**: SEVERE.
- [image] **CRITICAL**: Logging serious errors by Google App Engine, like when uncaught exceptions are propagated to servlet container causing HTTP 500 server error.